# How do I generate a random number sequence in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random

Is there any way to make a numerical sequence in python randomly but with a predefined range?

Example:

```
number = random range( 1,10 )
number = 6
```

Output:

```
Example 1: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to make a queue where every 1 minute a random number of people arrives between 3 to 11, and put each person individually as an element within a array.

Comment: [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

Comment: I tried but randint generates only a single intenger,  and not the sequence from the number 1 to the generated number

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
import random
number = [i for i in range(1 , random.randint(3 , 11)+1)]
```